# SQLite querybuilder BETWEEN clause

Tags: android, sqlite, between

I want to run this query in application:

`SELECT Naslov, Kraj FROM Bankomati_db WHERE Banka=selectedBank AND ((ZemljepisnaSirina BETWEEN selectedLatDPod AND selectedLatDNad) AND (ZemljepisnaDolzina BETWEEN selectedLngDPod AND selectedLngDNad))`

When I run it like this in DB browser it returns some rows, while in android doesn't.

I am using this code in application:

```
public Cursor getBankomatCoordinates(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    String [] sqlSelect = {"0 _id", "Naslov", "Kraj"};
    String sqlTables="Bankomati_db";
    String sqlWhere="Banka=? AND ((ZemljepisnaSirina BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND (ZemljepisnaDolzina BETWEEN ? AND ?))";
    String [] args = {selectedBank, selectedLatDPod, selectedLatDNad, selectedLngDPod, selectedLngDNad};

    qb.setTables(sqlTables);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, sqlWhere, args, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();

    return c;

}
```

Comment: While building query make sure your arguments are fed correctly. I see some faults.

Comment: First try using a rawQuery, and see if you get an output.
FYI: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])

Comment: rawQuery does'n work either, I tried rawQuery without variables it still doesnt work while in DB browser does.

`Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, Naslov, Kraj FROM Bankomati_db WHERE Banka = 'Banka Koper d.d.' AND ((ZemljepisnaSirina BETWEEN 45.6613605 AND 45.8613605) AND (ZemljepisnaDolzina BETWEEN 13.807992500000001 AND 14.0079925))", null);`

Comment: I think your SQL query id the problem. Try `SELECT Naslov FROM Bankomati_db WHERE Banka = Banka Koper AND (( ZemljepisnaSirina BETWEEN 45.6613605 AND 45.8613605 ) AND ( ZemljepisnaDolzina BETWEEN 13.807992500000001 AND 14.0079925 ))`

Comment: My suggestion is value has to be declared as a field inside class, and in SQLquery spacing in the statement has to be exact.

Comment: Can you show what you mean with that?